# Windows SBS 2011 Essentials User Documents Stored on Server (Folder re-direction?)

Tags: active-directory, windows-sbs, folder-redirection

On Windows SBS 2011 Essentials, how do you store user documents in a centralized location on the server?

For example a 'User' folder has sub-folders for Mr A, B and C. Each of these folders has all documents, desktop, downloads etc. for that user. Is this what folder re-direction is or is there another method for this siuation?

I have found information on this for SBS 2011 Standard but i dont think this applies to Essentials, is it even possible on Essentials?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is supported on Windows SBS 2011 Essentials. You'll need to install the [Windows 7 Pro Pack Add-in](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27122). Take a look at this [TechNet blog post](http://blogs.technet.com/b/sbs/archive/2011/08/05/windows-7-professional-pack-for-sbs-essentials-add-in-releases.aspx):

> With folder redirection the Pro Pack helps small businesses protect
>   the data stored on their client computers. Folder redirection is
>   designed to allow users to continue working in the same way saving
>   their data in real time on their client computer, but reduces the risk
>   of data loss by having the most important data on a particular
>   computer automatically redirected, stored and protected on the server
>   (when on the local domain). This way, even if the client computer is
>   lost or suffers critical damage, is it still possible to access the
>   latest set of data on the server when the client has not been backed
>   up recently. Best of all, when users edit local data when away from
>   the network, any small business can ensure that when the PC is back on
>   the local network, updated information is immediately replicated to
>   the server and protected.

Also take a look at some of the documentation:

[Understanding and using Server Folders for centralized storage](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/server-folders-overview-1.aspx)

> The following table lists the Server Folders that are created by
>   default when you install Windows SBS 2011 Essentials.
>
> > Server Folder name: Users
> >
> > Description: Used to store and access files by network users.
> >
> > A
> >     user specific folder is automatically generated in this Users server
> >     folder for every network user account that you create.

[How do I manage folders in the user’s shared folder?](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/manage-user-shared-folder-1.aspx)

> By default, when a user is created, a sub folder is created for the
>   user under the user folder. The sub-folder can be accessed only by the
>   user or the administrator from a network computer. Since the
>   permissions are set for each sub-folder under users, there are no
>   general access permissions for the top-level user folder

And since it seems you missed the TechNet documentation, here's a link to more information you should be reading:

[Windows Small Business Server 2011 Essentials Online Help for Administrators](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff357112.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the quick and informative reply, working through this now!